# late response from this function

Tags: android

when i single tap on screen then it takes about 1 minute to respond me.
why it is taking too much time

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
        addDelay("your current location is....  you are in FYP lab");
        addDelay("please tell me where you want to go");
            getInput();
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: where is addDelay() function?please paste

Comment: What other code do you have that's blocking the main thread?

Comment: addDelay() is just a function for text to speech output